# $e^XY$ and $Ye^X$

Tags: lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Let $X,Y$ be two matrices, and we define
$$
e^X:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}X^k
$$
In a problem about Lie algebras, I need to show if $[X,Y]=\alpha Y,\alpha\neq 2\pi ik$, then
$$
e^XY=\frac{\alpha}{1-e^{\alpha}}Ye^X
$$

I want to expand $e^X$ and see
$$
(I+X+\frac12X^2+\dots)Y=*Y(I+X+\frac12X^2+\dots)
$$
But things seem to be difficult. Is there any way easy to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hint: consider $U(t)=e^{tX}Y$ and examine $dU\over dt$

Comment: @user619894 Could you explain in more detail? since I'm doubting this equality will fail. Very thanks!

Comment: ${d U \over d t} = e^{tX} X Y= e^{tX} (X Y -Y X + Y X)= e^{tX} (\alpha Y + Y X)=U(\alpha +X)$ which can be integrated

Comment: There seems to be an easy way :

 $e^X=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}X^k \\ 
e^XY=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}X^kY $

For each $k$ :
$X^kY=X^{k-1}XY=X^{k-1}([XY]+YX)=X^{k-1}(\alpha Y+YX)\\=X^{k-1}Y(\alpha I+X)\\ =X^{k-2}Y(\alpha I+X)^2\\= ... = Y(\alpha I+X)^k$

So : $e^XY=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}X^kY=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}Y(\alpha I+x)^k= Ye^{\alpha I+X}=e^\alpha Ye^X$
But this is not the answer you expected..

Comment: @Olivier yeah I also find this method!

Comment: Answer clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)
$$
e^{X}Y e^{-X} = e^{\operatorname{ad} _X} Y =Y+\left[X,Y\right]+\frac{1}{2!}[X,[X,Y]]+\frac{1}{3!}[X,[X,[X,Y]]]+\cdots \\
=Y+\alpha Y +\frac{1}{2!}\alpha^2 Y +\frac{1}{3!} \alpha^3Y+\cdots = e^\alpha ~Y~~~\leadsto \\
e^{X}Y= e^\alpha Y e^{X},   \tag{*}
$$
which is not what you are seeking, but  your target expression is off. Convince yourself of that, perturbatively in *α*!

There is the more important identity in that article,
$$
e^X e^Y= e^{X+{\alpha \over 1-e^{-\alpha}}Y}, 
$$
but I can't tell what you might be up to...

NB The above identity (*) is more trivial than it looks. For $[\partial_z , e^{\alpha z} ]= \alpha  e^{\alpha z}$, you obtain a  straightforward *translation* by 1,
$$
 e^{\partial} e^{\alpha z}=e^{\alpha ( z+1)} e^{\partial} =e^{\alpha}e^{\alpha z } e^{\partial}, 
$$
used routinely in physics...